# sinon.stub() vs sinon.sandbox.stub()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, sinon

Using **sinon** and **sinon-qunit** in our front end unit tests, and I'm struggling to understand the difference in these methods. We are using `sinon.sandbox.stub()` (literally that is the function, we do not create a sandbox) and these stubs are apparently restored after each test automatically. I just don't see this anywhere in the documentation.

I wouldn't think that this method exists, I would think you would need to explicitly create a sandbox using `sinon.sandbox.create()`. On that sandbox object you would call the stub function, `i.e. mySandbox.stub()`, not `"sinon.sandbox.stub()"`.

Could anyone help me understand?

Comment: Are you sure you don't call `.restore()` in an `after()` block? The only thing it does extra is that it adds the stub to an internal list which, when call `.restore()` it restores all of the stubs inside.

Comment: We definitely don't call restore anywhere. My guess is the sinon-qunit framework is doing that behind the scenes.

Comment: According to the documentation it automatically restore all stubbed/spied `jQuery.ajax` fakes.

Answer (score 8):

**Stubs - Sinon.JS**

`sinon.stub();` read about from [here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/)

---

**Sandboxes - Sinon.JS**

`sandbox.stub();` read detail from [here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/sandbox/)

Works almost exactly like `sinon.stub`, only also adds the returned stub to the internal collection of fakes for easy restoring through `sandbox.restore()`.

The sandbox stub method can also be used to stub any kind of property. This is useful if you need to override an object’s property for the duration of a test, and have it restored when the test completes